# When div is visible on screen add .active class to li

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a page:
[Like This](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html)

When a div gets into the view on the screen, then a class gets added to the right side of the "table of contents", then when it's scrolled off the screen and another div shows up the class gets moved to the next "title" of the content.

So far I have a list of divs stacked on the top of each other and some basic JS but it does not work. I am not even sure if this is a good approach to get this done?

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if ( $('#field-wrap1').offset().top <= 100 ) {
    $('#slide-li1').addClass("active");
  }else{
    $('#slide-li1').removeClass("active");
  }
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sL85w2bn/)

Comment: I know probably by offsetting from the top is not a good idea, because once the page gets scrolled to the bottom div, how would I offset it from the top if the screen is portrait and has like 5000 px vertically?

Comment: Bootstrap has what they call a scrollspy that does this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/scrollspy/

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to load another library for just this function.

Comment: Consider using the `IntersectionObserver`API. No need for jQuery here.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!---
With this code it doesn't require editing the JavaScript
at all, only the HTML/CSS, it will apply the class .qqq_menu_active
to the active menu item and .qqq_section_active to the active section.
--->

<style>
* {
    font-family: Arial;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    font-size: 10pt;
}
.qqq_container {
    padding: 50px;
}
.qqq_menu {
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    left: 750px;
    top: 50px;
}
.qqq_menu_item {
    color: #333;
}
.qqq_menu_active {
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
}
.qqq_section {
    width: 600px;
    padding: 25px;
    color: #676767;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.qqq_section_active {
    color: #281c96;
    background-color: #bdb6ff;
}
h1 {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
</style>

<div class="qqq_menu">
<div class='qqq_menu_item'>section_1</div>
<div class='qqq_menu_item'>section_2</div>
<div class='qqq_menu_item'>section_3</div>
<div class='qqq_menu_item'>section_4</div>
<div class='qqq_menu_item'>section_5</div>
</div>

<div class='qqq_container'>
<div class='qqq_section'>
<h1>section_1</h1>
<p class='text_fill'></p>
</div>
<div class='qqq_section'>
<h1>section_2</h1>
<p class='text_fill'></p>
</div>
<div class='qqq_section'>
<h1>section_3</h1>
<p class='text_fill'></p>
</div>
<div class='qqq_section'>
<h1>section_4</h1>
<p class='text_fill'></p>
</div>
<div class='qqq_section'>
<h1>section_5</h1>
<p class='text_fill'></p>
</div>
</div>

<script>
// note: have tried editing .repeat to 3000 to make it a lot of text and 150 to make it a little text and still works right. also added a bunch of space with <br /> above and below the .qqq_container element and still works right.
asdf_text = "asdf ".repeat(750);
document.querySelectorAll(".text_fill").forEach(function (element) {
    element.innerHTML = asdf_text;
});
container = document.querySelectorAll(".qqq_container")[0];
sections = document.querySelectorAll(".qqq_section");
menu = document.querySelectorAll(".qqq_menu_item");

percentage = 0;
function qqq_menu_highlight() {
    active = 0;
    ttt = window.innerHeight / 100;
    lll = ttt * percentage;
    zzz = window.scrollY + lll;
    sections.forEach(function (v, k, l) {
        if (zzz > v.offsetTop) {
            active = k;
        }
    });
    menu.forEach(function (v, k, l) {
        if (active === k) {
            v.classList.add('qqq_menu_active');
        } else {
            v.classList.remove('qqq_menu_active');
        }
    });
    sections.forEach(function (v, k, l) {
        if (active === k) {
            v.classList.add('qqq_section_active');
        } else {
            v.classList.remove('qqq_section_active');
        }
    });
}
function element_scroll_percentage(element) {
    //inc = (document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight) / 100;
    //console.log(active);
    rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (Math.sign(rect.top) == -1) {
        value = Math.abs(rect.top);
        inc = (rect.height - window.innerHeight) / 100;
        percentage = value / inc;
        if (percentage > 100) {
            percentage = 100;
        }
    } else {
        percentage = 0;
    }
    return percentage;
}
document.onscroll = function() {
    percentage = element_scroll_percentage(container);
    qqq_menu_highlight();
    //console.log(percentage);
}
document.onscroll();
</script>
```

Comment: WOW! this is awesome, but if the paragraph is shorter, it will not roll down to the last ones. If you change this from 790 to 50 <p>${"asdf ".repeat(50)}</p> you will see.

Comment: Use the `IntersectionObserver` API.

Comment: I updated it, this time it doesn't require editing the JavaScript at all, it will apply the class .qqq_menu_active to the active menu item and .qqq_section_active to the active section.

Answer (score 0):

In the solution below, I divided the value of `this.scrollY` by `200`, since the `height` of the containers is `200px`. I added the result of this action to the end of the `slide-li` statement to use as the `id` of the targeted item.

```js
function removeClass() {
  for(let i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++)
    $(`#slide-li${i + 1}`).removeClass("active");
}

$(window).scroll(function(){
    console.clear();
    console.log(`Scroll: ${this.scrollY}`);
    
    removeClass();
    let visibleElement = Math.floor(this.scrollY / 200);
    $(`#slide-li${visibleElement + 1}`).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
#container {
     width: 800px;
     margin: auto;
     text-align: left;
     display: inline-flex;
     margin: 0;
     margin: 100px 0;
}
 #field {
     width: 500px;
     float: left;
     font-weight: 500;
     color: #001737;
}
 .field-wrap {
     padding: 0;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #8392A5;
     height: 200px;
     background-color: #FF000030;
}
 #slidecart {
     position: fixed;
     top: 10px;
     right: 0px;
     width: 300px;
     display: inline-block;
     padding: 20px;
     border-left: 1px solid #8392A5;
}
 #slide-ul {
     list-style-type: none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
 .slide-li {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0 0 0 10px;
     cursor: pointer;
}
 .active {
     padding: 0 0 0 5px;
     border-left: 5px solid #0168FA;
     color: #0168FA;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="field">
    <div id="field-wrap1" class="field-wrap">
      1.) - Hello World!
    </div>
    
    <div id="field-wrap2" class="field-wrap">
      2.) - Hello World!
    </div>
    
    <div id="field-wrap3" class="field-wrap">
      3.) - Hello World!
    </div>
    
    <div id="field-wrap4" class="field-wrap">
      4.) - Hello World!
    </div>
    
    <div id="field-wrap5" class="field-wrap">
      5.) - Hello World!
    </div>
    
    <div id="field-wrap6" class="field-wrap">
      6.) - Hello World!
    </div>
    
  </div>

  <div id="slidecart">
    TABLE OF CONTENTS
    <ul id="slide-ul">LIST
      <li id="slide-li1" class="slide-li">1.) - Hello World!</li>
      <li id="slide-li2" class="slide-li">2.) - Hello World!</li>
      <li id="slide-li3" class="slide-li">3.) - Hello World!</li>
      <li id="slide-li4" class="slide-li">4.) - Hello World!</li>
      <li id="slide-li5" class="slide-li">5.) - Hello World!</li>
      <li id="slide-li6" class="slide-li">6.) - Hello World!</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: so what if the divs wil lhave different heights and can not be divided by 200? Is there a way somehow to check if they are showing in the screen somewhere or off the screen?

Comment: Being the same height only made it easier for me to express the solution mathematically. If the heights are different, it will be enough to check one by one starting from the first container.

Comment: Additionally, you can use the [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/getting-started/) library. [Demo Application](https://codepen.io/hafizfattah/pen/kKyMMZ)

Comment: `IntersectionObserver` API